# Architecture docs/diagrams of OTP?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I'm newbie to erlang. I'm curious about the design of Open Telecom Platform. Is there a design document of OTP itself or pictorial representation of the implementation of OTP in erlang. I tried googling and browsing official docs but all I could get was the architecture of OTP based app, but, couldn't find architectural structure of OTP itself.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is thesis [Making reliable distributed systems in the presence of software errors](https://www.sics.se/~joe/thesis/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) written by [Joe Armstrong](https://www.sics.se/~joe/). The work contains fundamentals of which is OTP based on and there is also a very simplified implementation of basic OTP modules.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like what I need, but is there more detailed explanation of OTP?

Comment: @user2215912: There is [OTP Design Principles User's Guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/users_guide.html) in Erlang/OTP documentation which is a good introduction to OTP especially after Joe's thesis. OTP was organically developed for a purpose and practical industry usage. You can of course study source code, but Joe's thesis is a perfect theoretical basis to understand it from a global point of view.

Comment: Looks like this the answer I need. Thank you.